# Overflow issue in cascading CSS menu

Tags: css, position, overflow

I have a simple CSS-based drop down menu that is working fine. But now I want to add a sub-menu that will display as well. Everything is working fine, except the height on the main menu list is expanding when the sub menu is displayed.

http://jsfiddle.net/GzfFs/

```
.cascade_content {
/* cascading sub menu */
display: none;
z-index: 103;
position: relative;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #8C8C8C;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
width: 190px;
left: -192px;
top: -26px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0px #8C8C8C;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0px #8C8C8C;
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0px #8C8C8C;
```

}

Note: it seems like position:relative in the sub menu is causing this... however, changing that to position:absolute creates the problem of it not appearing in the right place. I'm sure those of you with more CSS experience will identify this as a simple issue - appreciate any help you can offer!

Comment: Seems like a whole lot of JS for a simple menu. It could probably be all done with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/GzfFs/1/

```
.dropdown_content li {position: relative}
.cascade_content {position: absolute}
```

You may also need to move your ULs inside the LIs to get positioning where you want it.

Comment: Yes but as mentioned, simply changing position absolute that way causes the sub menu to be displayed at the top rather than next to the parent item in the main menu list).

Comment: Yup. Did you see what I wrote below the CSS? I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect that your markup is invalid, having ULs between LIs anyway They should be *inside* the LIs.

Comment: ok thanks - I see what you mean. Should be able to get there from here. Thank you!